# Prevent nested C++ struct from being deleted when parent is GC'd

Tags: c++, python, swig

Here is a pretty trivial example of the problem I'm having. struct Foo contains struct Bar which contains one int. If a Foo is garbage collected, then its inner Bar is also removed, even if there are still references to that bar.

**Python code**

```
import example

def get_bar():
    foo = example.Foo()
    foo.bar.x = 10
    bar = foo.bar
    print("before {}".format(bar.x))
    return foo.bar # foo (and bar) are deleted when this returns

bar = get_bar()
print("after {}".format(bar.x))
```

**Output**

```
> before 10
> after 39656152
```

I've eliminated all pointers and references from the C++ code, hoping that SWIG would use the same value semantics, but it is still internally converting things to Foo* and Bar*. I guess my question is, how can I convince SWIG to make a copy of bar in _wrap_Foo_bar_get?

Example code below:

**example.h**

```
struct Bar {
  int x;
};
struct Foo {
  Bar bar;
};
```

**example.i**

```
%module "example"
%{
  #include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH} .)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i example.h)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

And here is the generated SWIG method that is grabbing a reference to bar rather its value:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_Foo_bar_get(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  Foo *arg1 = (Foo *) 0 ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  Bar *result = 0 ;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"O:Foo_bar_get",&obj0)) SWIG_fail;
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_Foo, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "Foo_bar_get" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "Foo *""'"); 
  }
  arg1 = reinterpret_cast< Foo * >(argp1);
  result = (Bar *)& ((arg1)->bar);
  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Bar, 0 |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for shared_ptr's.

Comment: Since you're using SWIG I won't post this as an answer, but if you were using Boost Python to do your wrapping it would give choices like `copy_const_reference` and `return_internal_reference` to manage the lifetimes appropriately (by copying or by extending the container's lifetime to that of the contained object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG (and Boost Python) are fighting an uphill battle by interfacing between languages with very different data models. You are making that battle that much harder (unwinnable) by expecting those SWIG-wrapped objects to behave exactly like other Python objects. They don't because they can't. The C++ and Python data models are quite different.

In C++, that `Bar` instance that is embedded within class `Foo` is an integral part of a `Foo` object. The memory occupied by that embedded `Bar` object is a part of the overall memory for that containing `Foo` object. When `foo` goes out of scope and is destructed, `foo.bar` must necessarily go out of scope and be destructed along with it's containing object. Your `foo.bar` is not detachable from `foo`. The two objects have identical lifespans.

That's not the case in Python. A Python object that contains a sub-object doesn't contain that sub-object in the C++ sense. The memory for the containing and contained objects are distinct and non-overlapping. The containing object instead has a reference to the contained sub-object. This makes those sub-objects in Python detachable from the objects that contain them. Just get a separate reference reference to that sub-object and voila!, the containing and contained objects have different life spans.

One way around this problem is to use smart pointers in your C++ code. SWIG does support these to some extent. Another way around this problem is to never let it rear its ugly head. Be aggressive with data hiding in the code that you are exposing to SWIG. The problem never arises if that `Bar` object embedded within that `Foo` object is properly hidden. Use the member functions, not the member data, and you'll be much better off.

One final word: There is another, somewhat kludgy, way around this problem, and that's to use the `thisown` attribute. Had you set `foo.thisown = 0` in your Python function `get_bar` you wouldn't have had this problem. You would have had a leak, however.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the detailed answer. I see that I have more control when wrapping foo.get_bar() rather than foo.bar. Here is one more complication: what if if instead of Foo I have a std::vector<Bar>? It's sounding like I have no choice but to use shared_ptr in this case?

Comment: There are plenty of other choices. For example, you could set `bar.thisown=0` when get a reference to an element in that `std::vector<Bar>`. The Python code doesn't "own" the objects in that `vector. The vector does. With SWIG, you have to be cognizant of which code, the C++ code or the Python code, owns what. Or you could make a copy of the SWIG-wrapped object in Python. Then you have two different objects, one owned by C++ and one by Python.

Comment: Sorry I'm apparently still a little confused. In `get_bar()`, `bar.thisown` is already false. Do you mean that I would have to set `thisown=0` on the _vector_ to prevent the whole thing from being deleted?